# How can I add a label to a panel inside a button's Action Listener?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

I want when you click to button it adds a label on a panel. Outside of the Action Listener works fine, but inside doesn't do anything, nothing error code or anything.
(Some parts of the code missing, I deleted because I think there isn't relevant that)

```
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
panel1.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2, true));
panel1.setBounds(60, 80, 128, 128);
frmmain.getContentPane().add(panel1);

JLabel label1 = new JLabel ();

JButton btnTest = new JButton("Test");
btnTest.setFont(new Font("Bahnschrift", Font.PLAIN, 21));
btnTest.setBounds(240, 367, 121, 57);

btnTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try 
            {
                 panel1.add(label1);
                
            }
            catch (Exception e2) 
            {
                System.err.println(e2);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: try to panel.revalidate() and panel1.repaint() after adding the label. When you add components while they are visible, a repaint/revalidate is always a good idea regardless if these new components are visible or not.

Comment: Also, avoid using `setBounds` method for any component. Panels should using LayoutManagers and the UI should be built by LayoutManagers. Hardcoding `setBounds` is bad idea. Your UI wont be "working" in different screen sizes/resolutions.

Comment: Thanks it is worked. 

Yeah I know the setbounds thing I need to learn other layouts in java. (I know only just the absolut)